# How to test a Jersey rest service using mock objects

Tags: java, rest, mocking, jersey, integration-testing

I have developed a rest service using Jersey. Now I want to write some integration tests for this web service but since not every class being used from the web service is already implemented I need to mock some of them. For example I have the following class:

```
public class A {

    private String getWeather() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My web service looks like this :

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET 
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt() {
        A a = new A();
        return a.getWeather();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the getWeather function is not ready so I need to mock the return value for this function. But for the integration test where I issue a rest call I don't know how to do that.

Are there any ideas?

Comment: well did you try using Mockito? You may be able to mock the call to `getWeather` and return a `test string` object for the tests. Have a look https://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Comment: This doesn't work because inside the rest resource a new instance of the A class is created therefore the mock object is not being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to achieve this using `Power Mockito` (https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyResource.class })
public class MyResourceTest {

   @Test
   public void testGetIt()() {
     MyResource mr = new MyResource();

     //Setup mock
     A mockA = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);

     String mockReturn = "Some String";

     //Stub new A() with your mock
     PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockA);
     PowerMockito.doReturn(mockReturn).when(mockA).getWeather();
     String ret = mr.getIt();

     //asserts go here
   }
}
```

Note that you can mock a local variable creation using PowerMockito's `whenNew` - this should take care of your concern for `A a = new A()` code in `getIt()` method.

Comment: Since I want to run an integration test I do not create an instance of MyResource but I invoke the service using a Rest Client. I tried to use mockito but it does not use the mocked function but the original one.

Comment: Actually it works if it used along with the Jersey Test Framework ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Be aware that powermock alters your class files to be able to do this. I would suggest making your design more testable rather than using powermock. Powermock is an excellent tool for putting tests on legacy systems but should not be used when developing new stuff. (IMO... :-) )

Comment: @Pat : prepareForTest should be A.class, Isnt it ?

Answer (score 3):

To make your design decoupled from A you should pass it in as a parameter to MyResource. Then you can easily mock it by hand or with mockito. With constructor injection it would look like this:

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    private A a;

    public MyResource(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @GET 
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt() {
        return a.getWeather();
    }
}
```

and you can test it with

```
@Test
public void shouldGetIt() {
    A a = mock(A.class);
    when(a.getWeather()).thenReturn("sunny!");

    MyResource r = new MyResource(a);
    assertThat(r.getIt(), is("sunny!));
}
```

This makes your design decoupled. MyResource no longer depends on A directly but on anything that looks lik an A. Another benefit is that mockito doesn't mess with you class files. It is your code that is tested - not something that has been generated on the fly.

Many consider injection by constructor to be a bit old school. I am old so I like it.... With spring (a framework I don't recommend that you pick up) you can autowire variables like so:

```
@Autowire
private A a;
```

and you don't need the constructor at all. Spring will find a the only implementation of A and insert it in this variable. I prefer explicit programming so I would chose constructor injection any day.